# Como fazer um deserialize em um Json com C-sharp

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, app

Tenho o seguinte código

```
private void WbRanking_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
                //lstRanking = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
                var obj = JsonValue.Parse(json);
                //var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
                JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));

                ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, obj);

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.Value != null)
                    {
                        //string nome = obj[0];
                        lstRanking.Add("Nome " + obj[0] + "Sobrenome " + obj[1]);
                    }

                    lsvRanking.Adapter = adapter;
                }
            });
        }
```

Como é possível ver na imagem o `var obj` está recebendo com sucesso o Json de uma api rest que tenho local. Mas na hora de colocar as informações na `listview` o sistema me retorna este erro conforme a imagem.

Agradeço desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

normalmente para serializar e deserializar coisas utilizo o Newtonsoft json, nas comparações é mais rápido que o do próprio c# e é bem simples de usar.

Tem no Nuget, que faciliata bastante obter o pacote :D

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Não conenheço os metodos que voce esta chamando mas normalmente utilizo assim

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

void PersonToJsonToPersonExample ()
{
    var person = new Person { Name = "Bob", Birthday = new DateTime (1987, 2, 2) };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (person);
    Console.WriteLine ("JSON representation of person: {0}", json);
    var person2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person> (json);
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1}", person2.Name, person2.Birthday);
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu já estou utilizando mas não está funcionando.

Comment: não sabia direito como colocar aqui atualizei a resposta... hehehe